# new feature or addon for map mode scrollbars?

Tags: visual-studio

probably a quick one:

what is this **grey waves** left oft the map mode of scroll bars?

[scroll bar http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-10-92-metablogapi/4265.image_5F00_12B0AD0A.png](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-10-92-metablogapi/4265.image_5F00_12B0AD0A.png)

2nd last screenshot from article here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnstudents/archive/2014/01/21/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-enhanced-scroll-bar.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with some luck I found it is part of the **Productivity Power Tools 2015**
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d

it seems to show the scope of blocks/braces.

Scrollbar markers

The blocks are also marked on the Scrollbar with previews. As usual, you can turn this on/off through Tools Options > Productivity Power Tools > Other extensions > Show code structure in the margin.
[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i1.visualstudiogallery.msdn.s-msft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace/image/file/117193/1/6.%20structure%20preview.png))</sub>

I saw it in a MVA video, and it was not the first time, they use tools or features they do not explain...

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature in Visual Studio 2013. You can preview the code by just hovering over the scroll bar & not actually scrolling. The width of the scroller could be adjusted (according to the 2nd link in your question - 2 last screenshot has Wide as the width).

How to set it?

**Tools -> Options -> All languages -> Scroll Bars**

All settings wrt to scroll bar are present here.

Comment: when I set mine to wide there are no such "waves". The questions only belongs to the waves, because everything else is explained. (tested VS 2015 two different versions and computers)